# perf error: failed to mmap with 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device)

Tags: perf-event, perf

I am trying to use perf in a system with 3.8 linux kernel.
When I used the following command, error happens:

```
$ perf record -c 100000 -e '{cycles,instructions}:S' ./nonloop 1000
failed to mmap with 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
nonloop: Terminated
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like :S is the problem.

```
perf record -c 100000 -ecycles,instructions ./somebin
```

runs fine. What is :S ?

I'm seeing a similar error running:

```
sudo perf record -esyscalls:sys_enter -p $(pidof some_bin)

failed to mmap with 22 (Invalid argument)
```

where perf list suggests syscalls:sys_enter should be available.